# Python Pandas - selecting a column by name is returning a Series instead of a float64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am missing something simple.

I have a dataframe called sorted_prediction_output which contains:

```
     fl_key   min_time_stamp  max_time_stamp     prediction
0    10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           1
1    10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           0
2    10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           0
3    10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           1
4    10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           1
5    10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           1
6    10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           2
7    10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           1
8    10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           1
9    10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           1
10   10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           1
11   10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           0
12   10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           1
13   10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           1
14   10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           2
```

I have a variable called counter which equals 0.

When I execute:

```
print(sorted_prediction_output.iloc[[counter]])
```

I get:

```
    fl_key   min_time_stamp  max_time_stamp     prediction
0   10051    1.614557e+12    1.614557e+12           1
```

This makes sense.  However, when I execute:

```
print(sorted_prediction_output.iloc[[counter]].min_time_stamp)
```

I get:

```
    min_time_stamp
0   1.614557e+12
```

Why am I getting a Series back and what do I do to get back the value of min_time_stamp column in the 0th row?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Remove one pair of square brackets. `[...]` instead of `[[...]]`

Comment: @Cyttorak - Thanks a bunch.  I knew it was something simple and I was too tired to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:
`print(sorted_prediction_output.iloc[[counter]].min_time_stamp.sum())`